# How to compare an element of a 2D array with rest of the its elements?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I know I can use a single array to do this, but if I do use a single array it will make the question that I am doing harder for me. Say for instance I had a 2D-array:

```cpp
[["E", "A"], ["R", "B"], ["C", "D"]]
```

How do I compare each element it with the rest of the elements? E.g. "E" is compared with "A", "R", "B" etc. The 2D array will always consist of 1 by 2 sub-arrays. Please can anyone help me, thank you.

Comment: Compare and then what? What do you need to do with the results of such comparisons? What ultimate problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Sorry, the title is supposed to be "How to compare an element with the rest of the elements of a 2d array"

Comment: Please show some of your coding efforts and also add where you're having the problem, if possible, then add the I/O.

Comment: Here's a simple way to figure out how to do this, and it never fails to work. Just take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down using short, simple sentences in plain English, a step-by-step process of doing this. When done, [call your rubber duck for an appointment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). We don't write entire programs for other people, on Stackoverflow. We always refer such questions to your rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished!

Comment: After getting a solution to compare the elements, I will be able to hopefully finish the question I was doing. Unfortunately, I have not done much coding because the comparing part of the question was very important, hence without it I could not do much. I do not want to post the whole question I was doing because the only part that I am struggling with is comparing the elements. I have been searching for over an hour on different websites including stack overflow, but I could find my answer anywhere. Please can you help me.

Comment: @sam I have given an answer that works using only forloops

Comment: If it is always an X x 2 2D array, just loop `for (int i = 0; i < X; i++) { if (array[i][0] == array[i][1]) /* characters match */ }` It's pretty simple with only 2-chars per-row.

Comment: To compare elements in a single array you can simply use a nested for loop, right? like this: for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) (Just pretend this for loop is under the first for loop) for(int j = i + 1; j < array.size(); j++),  in this loop each element  can get compared with all the elements after it. I want the code to do the same thing except with a 2d array.  I do not want this code to give an output, I just want a piece of code that compares each element with the rest of the elements, like the nested for loop above.

Comment: The question I am doing is on leetcode and it is called 'destination city.' I believe it requires hashmaps (because all the c++ solutions used hashmaps), however I have no experience with hashmaps at all, hence I trying to do the question with for loops instead.

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    int arr[2][2] = {
    {1,2},
    {3,4},
    };
    int elem;
    for (int i = 0;i < 2;i++){
        for(int j = 0;j < 2;j++){
            //Now you're on the first element
            // I have used a size of 2, but you can use whatever size you want
            elem = arr[i][j];
            for (int a = 0;a < 2;a++){
                for(int b = 0;b < 2;b++){
                    if (arr[a][b] == elem) continue;
                    //Do whatever you want now;
                    std::cout << "Comparing " << elem << " with " << arr[a][b] << "\n";
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This is the output

```
Comparing 1 with 2
Comparing 1 with 3
Comparing 1 with 4
Comparing 2 with 1
Comparing 2 with 3
Comparing 2 with 4
Comparing 3 with 1
Comparing 3 with 2
Comparing 3 with 4
Comparing 4 with 1
Comparing 4 with 2
Comparing 4 with 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <array>       // std::array
#include <utility>     // std::pair
    
using namespace std;
    
int main()
{
    // build objects
    pair<char, char> element1('E', 'A');
    pair<char, char> element2('R', 'B');
    pair<char, char> element3('C', 'D');
    array<pair<char, char>, 3> my_array = {element1, element2, element3};

    // perform comparisons
    for (int i = 0; int i != my_array.size(); ++i) {
        yourCompareFunction(my_array[i].first, my_array[i].second);
        for (int j = i + 1; int j != my_array.size(); ++j) {
            yourCompareFunction(my_array[i].first, my_array[j].first); 
            yourCompareFunction(my_array[i].first, my_array[j].second);
            yourCompareFunction(my_array[i].second, my_array[j].first); 
            yourCompareFunction(my_array[i].second, my_array[j].second);
         };
    };

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but, this is not exactly what I am looking for :)

Comment: That compares each `char` element of the array with any other. Unless you meant the single elements to be compared among themselves should have been the array rows (i.e. the `pair`s element1, element2 etc in my implementation). If that's the case, then you may want to set up a separate comparePairs(`pair` a, `pair` b) function.